# maven-site-plugin to skip Generating "Test Javadoc" report --- maven-javadoc-plugin

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

What I am trying to achieve:

Generate project website from maven site plugin, without the javadoc for tests (but with javadoc for the classes)

What did I try:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0-M8</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/javadoc</outputDirectory>
                    <reportOutputDirectory>target/javadoc</reportOutputDirectory>
                    <javadocExecutable>${java.home}/bin/javadoc</javadocExecutable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

`mvn clean install site -U javadoc:javadoc`

Issue:

reproducible 100%, I am seeing this error:

```
[INFO] Rendering site for default locale
Downloading from spring-milestones: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.1.0-M2/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.1.0-M2-site.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.1.0-M2/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.1.0-M2-site.xml
Downloading from spring-milestones: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/3.1.0-M2/spring-boot-dependencies-3.1.0-M2-site.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/3.1.0-M2/spring-boot-dependencies-3.1.0-M2-site.xml
[WARNING] Unable to find a URL to the parent project. The parent menu will NOT be added.
[INFO] Relativizing decoration links with respect to localized project URL: http://example.com/abc
[INFO] Rendering content with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-fluido-skin:jar:2.0.0-M2 skin.
[INFO] Skipped "Javadoc" report (maven-javadoc-plugin:3.5.0:javadoc), file "apidocs/index.html" already exists.
[INFO] Skipped "Javadoc" report (maven-javadoc-plugin:3.5.0:javadoc-no-fork), file "apidocs/index.html" already exists.
[INFO] Skipped "Test Javadoc" report (maven-javadoc-plugin:3.5.0:test-javadoc), file "testapidocs/index.html" already exists.
[INFO] Skipped "Test Javadoc" report (maven-javadoc-plugin:3.5.0:test-javadoc-no-fork), file "testapidocs/index.html" already exists.
[INFO] Skipped "Source Xref" report (maven-jxr-plugin:3.3.0:jxr-no-fork), file "xref/index.html" already exists.
[INFO] Skipped "Test Source Xref" report (maven-jxr-plugin:3.3.0:test-jxr-no-fork), file "xref-test/index.html" already exists.
[INFO] Generating "Javadoc" report       --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.5.0:aggregate-no-fork
[INFO] No previous run data found, generating javadoc.
[INFO] Generating "Test Javadoc" report  --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.5.0:test-aggregate-no-fork
[INFO] Configuration changed, re-generating javadoc.
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Skipping abc
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  28.498 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-10T08:45:32+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:4.0.0-M6:site (default-site) on project abc: Error generating maven-javadoc-plugin:3.5.0:test-aggregate-no-fork report:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1
[ERROR] error: No public or protected classes found to document.
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR] Command line was: cmd.exe /X /C "xxx\bin\javadoc.exe @options @packages"
[ERROR]
```

Question:

How to generate a project website with maven site plugin, with the javadoc for the classes, but not the javadoc for the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/selective-javadocs-report.html)

> To run the Javadocs reports selectively, you need to include only the Javadocs reports that you prefer.

You can skip generating Javadoc for the tests by removing it from the config

```xml
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
           ....
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <show>public</show>
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <reports>
                            <report>javadoc</report>
                            <!-- <report>test-javadoc</report> -->
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                    <reportSet>
                        <id>aggregate</id>
                        <reports>
                            <report>aggregate</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        ...
    </reporting>
```